# facebook - member in a group can't see admin post or comments in specified group

Tags: facebook, comments

I am a member of several Facebook groups
In one of the groups I suddenly stopped seeing posts and comments from administrators in the group.

The administrators did not take any action towards me that could cause this malfunction.
Once I was made a temporary modorator it solved the problem.
I went back to being a normal user and the problem returned.
In this group each manager uses his own user to manage and not a single management user.
In the other groups I am a member of, everything works properly and I see posts and comments from managers.
I am in collaboration with the managers in the same group
Can't solve the problem and it's very important for me to see posts and comments from managers in the same group.
I would appreciate your help in finding a solution to the problem.